# Como obter um Type apartir de uma string

Tags: c#, vb.net, reflexão, .net-assembly

Por exemplo, quero que uma string contendo a informação `"System.Windows.Forms.Button"` retorne um objeto de botão `New Button()`, seria isso possível?

> **Nota:** Tem a tag <kbd>C#</kbd> pois é fácil traduzir do C# para o Visual Basic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a função `CreateInstance`, informando todo o caminho para a classe:

```
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Button"));
```

Você também pode usar um cast na criação da variável para uma classe que você tem certeza que é pai da que você está criando, por exemplo:

```
var obj = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Button"));
```

Dessa forma você poderá utilizar as funções da classe `Control` facilmente.